# Arraylist not working, items do not stack up

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-asynctask

So, I am trying to get some info from `database` and save it into an `ArrayList`, so later I can add dinamically `buttons` according to the `length` and `items` from that list.

code:

```
private List<String> probleme = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    if (SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).isLoggedIn()) {
        CautaProbleme();
        for(int i=0; i<probleme.size(); i++) {
            Button myButton = new Button(this);
            myButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            myButton.setText(probleme.get(i));
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_home);
            layout.addView(myButton);
        }
    }`
```

CautaProbleme method:

```
private void CautaProbleme(){
    class CautaProbleme extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        User user = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getUser();
        final String departament = String.valueOf(user.getDepartament());
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            //creating request handler object
            RequestHandler requestHandler = new RequestHandler();

            //creating request parameters
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("departament", departament);

            //returing the response
            return requestHandler.sendPostRequest(URLs.URL_PROBLEME, params);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            //displaying the progress bar while user registers on the server
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            //hiding the progressbar after completion

            try {
                //converting response to json object
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);

                //if no error in response
                if (!obj.getBoolean("error")) {
                    JSONArray problemeArray = obj.getJSONArray("probleme");
                    for (int i = 0; i < problemeArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject problema = problemeArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        // Verificare daca s-au primit probleme trimise de server
                        if (!problema.isNull("Problema")) {
                            String situatie = problema.getString("Problema");
                            probleme.add(situatie);
                        }
                    }

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Some error occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    CautaProbleme ru =new CautaProbleme();
    ru.execute();
}
```

The `JSON` response it's alright, the `problemeArray` looks good, but the problem it's that the `.add()` command does not add the `strings` to the list, so the `for` for creating `buttons` does not do anything, having an empty `list`. I have declared `private List probleme = new ArrayList<>();` globally.

Comment: When you start a method name with a capital letter it makes it harder to read for experienced developers. Please follow the recommended naming conventions
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-naming-conventions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AsyncTask` executes asynchronously, so you have to wait till finish the execution to get data. Better options is to use a callback to invoke when operation completed.

**Step - 1:** Remove button creation code from `onCreate` and add it in callback

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ....

    if (SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).isLoggedIn()) {
        CautaProbleme();
    }
}
```

Add callback function and update logic here

```
private void createButtonDynamically() {
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_home);

    for (int i = 0; i < probleme.size(); i++) {
        Button myButton = new Button(this);
        myButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        myButton.setText(probleme.get(i));
        layout.addView(myButton);
    }
}
```

**Step - 2:** Invoke callback from `onPostExecute` when operation finish

```
class CautaProbleme extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    ....

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        ....

        createButtonDynamically();
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm right now. Indeed I did not think about waiting until the `AsyncTask` finishes.

Answer (score 0):

CautaProbleme run in background while you proceed to the `for` loop.
You should send an interface with `onReady()` method to the `ASyncTask`and call it from `onPostExecute`.

Then, where you implement (Activity) `onReady()`, you can do

```
 for(int i=0; i<probleme.size(); i++) {
        Button myButton = new Button(this);
        myButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        myButton.setText(probleme.get(i));
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_home);
        layout.addView(myButton);
    }
```